# Using NetworkX all_simple_paths gives AttributeError

Tags: python, networkx, adjacency-matrix

I have a graph with adjacency matrix of the form below (a 6-node graph where self-edges are 0 and no_connections are marked Inf and other edges are 1):

```
{1: {1: 0, 2: 1, 3: inf, 4: inf, 5: inf, 6: inf}, 2: {1: 1, 2: 0, 3: inf, 4: 1, 5: 1, 6: inf}, 3: {1: inf, 2: inf, 3: 0, 4: 1, 5: inf, 6: inf}, 4: {1: inf, 2: 1, 3: 1, 4: 0, 5: 1, 6: 1}, 5: {1: inf, 2: 1, 3: inf, 4: 1, 5: 0, 6: inf}, 6: {1: inf, 2: inf, 3: inf, 4: 1, 5: inf, 6: 0}}
```

I want to use networkx package for its all_simple_paths function to find all simple paths from a source to a destination but when I call

```
nx.all_simple_paths(graph, src, dst)
```

it gives:
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'is_multigraph'

I currently do not have the graph in any other format. How should I resolve this issue?

Thanks.

Comment: why even give weights of `inf` if there's no connection?  Why not just leave them out of the dictionary entirely?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your graph is currently stored as a dictionary.  It's a little unfair to expect networkx to work automagically on any data structure you choose.  Even if it were set up to handle a dictionary in the way you've done it, how would it know how to interpret a 0 or `inf`?

To use networkx commands you'll need your graph to be in the networkx Graph format.

```
import networkx as nx
D = {1: {1: 0, 2: 1, 3: float('inf'), 4: float('inf'), 5: float('inf'), 6: float('inf')}, 2: {1: 1, 2: 0, 3: float('inf'), 4: 1, 5: 1, 6: float('inf')}, 3: {1: float('inf'), 2: float('inf'), 3: 0, 4: 1, 5: float('inf'), 6: float('inf')}, 4: {1: float('inf'), 2: 1, 3: 1, 4: 0, 5: 1, 6: 1}, 5: {1: float('inf'), 2: 1, 3: float('inf'), 4: 1, 5: 0, 6: float('inf')}, 6: {1: float('inf'), 2: float('inf'), 3: float('inf'), 4: 1, 5: float('inf'), 6: 0}}

G=nx.Graph()
for node, neighbor_dict in D.items():
    G.add_node(node)
    for neighbor, val in neighbor_dict.items():
        if val !=0 and val <float('inf'):
            G.add_edge(node, neighbor, weight=val)

for path in nx.all_simple_paths(G,1,3):
    print path
>[1, 2, 4, 3]
>[1, 2, 5, 4, 3]
```